# ActionScript 3 Pie Chart

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using Adobe Flash Professional and I am in need of creating a Pie Chart which updates when a frame is opened using integer variables.

I have been searching around but I can't find anything conclusive which I can get to work, any  help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is more about answering questions and solving issues that you have, rather than straight up coding it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/joshtynjala/astra-flash ,  this components set has a lot of charts, including pie-chart.